# How to fix an error message issue of security update available for my version of Drupal?

Tags: security, drupal, drupal-7, admin, drupal-8

I can see this error message on Drupal admin panel.

> There is a security update available for your version of Drupal. To
>   ensure the security of your server, you should update immediately! See
>   the available updates page for more information and to install your
>   missing updates. There are security updates available for one or more
>   of your modules or themes. To ensure the security of your server, you
>   should update immediately! See the available updates page for more
>   information and to install your missing updates.

I tried to no display error message on this page, 
Home » Administration » Configuration » Development
[image]

But I see this error message now.
[image]
Is this a version update issue? It enables, please help me. Thanks

Comment: Why disable this display ? If you hide errors you'll nt see all issue etc.. , so you can disable automtique update checker but don't hide all errors

Comment: thx, so what can I do hide or fix this error?

Comment: like @lastYosh suggested below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is shown by the update module. For what I know there are no configuration to disable this message. It is shown just for the users with the `administer site configuration` permission.

I think the only solution is to disable the update module.
If you use drush you can do:

```
drush pm-disable -y update
```

Usually in the development enviroment I keep enable the update module and I disable it in the production enviroment.

Comment: The other comments like "you should update Drupal" are not helpful. On a government site with approved Drupal version behind the latest, AND with a dev/stage/prod deployment process, AND with change control board AND with inflexible admin review, you want to disable the message. In that case it is OK to disable update module.  This answer worked for me in that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You should update Drupal and/or your installed insecure modules instead of trying to "hide" the message.

Check available security updates with drush: `drush pm-updatestatus --security-only`