# which version of drupal shall i use for my new website?

Tags: drupal

i have installed drupal 7.39 for my website but it had some issues. I have included the error message here. Anyone please help me out

**There is a security update available for your version of Drupal. To ensure the security of your server, you should update immediately! See the available updates page for more information and to install your missing updates.**

Comment: Did you See the available updates page for more information and to install your missing updates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix an error message issue of security update available for my version of Drupal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45957732/how-to-fix-an-error-message-issue-of-security-update-available-for-my-version-of)

Comment: Update as soon as possible to the newest 7.x release as in the meanwhile some very serious security updates got released.

Comment: Drupal 7.59 as of today.